# Good way to host private html documentation?

Tags: github, documentation-viewer

I have a project written in Typescript, following doc-style comment rules. I use TypeDoc to generate documentation, which outputs a bunch of html files.

I need a good way to host these files so that my coworkers can easily view the documentation *without being public*.

The only solution so-far seems to be to use TypeDoc-markdown, which is very ugly and has far fewer ui/ux features than the generated html.

Ideally, this would be hosted in one of the places we already use: github, confluence, or somewhere in aws, but I'm open to anything as long as it isn't ridiculously expensive

Comment: All of the hosting services that you mention are capable of hosting your documents as html files privately - you just need to set up a team account of some sort, manage the team members & __of course__ pay the fees. How much generally depends on the size of the team.